# Assigning one route to multiple user without a package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, user-roles, laravel-authentication

I have created four user type `admin,vendor,employee,customer`. In the user migration file I have the following:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->char('contact',24)->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->enum('roles',['admin', 'vendor', 'employee', 'customers']);
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I have already created middleware for all user type.
**Admin middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user()->roles == 'admin'){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route($request->user()->roles);
    }
}
```

**Customer middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user()->roles == 'customer'){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route($request->user()->roles);
    }
}
```

**Vendor middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user()->roles == 'vendor'){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route($request->user()->roles);
    }
}
```

**Employee middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user()->roles == 'employee'){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route($request->user()->roles);
    }
}
```

I have included all the middleware in the `Kernel.php`.
Now I want to assign one route to multiple users. For example, Admin and vendor can `add`, `edit`, `update`, `delete` product while Employee can only `edit`, s/he can neither `add` nor `delete`. I want to sensitive route to admin only.

Answer with explanation will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you are in an early design stage, I would definitely think about utilizing Gates, as described here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization . Might give you more fine grained control..

Comment: Gates are good as @wschopohl said. You can checkout Policies too, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies.

Comment: @wschopohl Thank you but I am not in the early stage of development. This feature was added later.

Comment: @KurtFriars Can you please help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167346/authorizing-resource-controllers-in-laravel-post-does-not-work?

Comment: highly recommended to not use enum types in database, its more creating problems(in future) till solving it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe another this solution is better rather than having multiple middlewars. by the way all them kind of doing same thing. so build a middleware and pass the use roles you need :)
this link is great and simple example:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Middlewares/RoleMiddleware.php

so you would have:

```
Route::middleware('roles:admin|customer')->get('/user', function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the route::prefix will work. Just separate the routes using the Route::prefix helper

Comment: Thinking  will not come to  answers section, Assumptions will go to the comments