# Authorizing Resource Controllers in Laravel Post does not work?

Tags: laravel, policy, laravel-authorization

I have created a ProductPolicy where I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Vendor;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ProductPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

public function before($user, $ability){
    if($user->roles == 'admin' || $user->roles == 'editor'){
        return true;
    }
}

public function viewAny(User $user)
{
    return true;
}

public function view(User $user, Product $product)
{
    $vendor_id = Vendor::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id')->first();
    return $vendor_id === $product->vendor_id;
}

public function create(User $user)
{
    return true;
}

public function update(User $user, Product $product)
{
    $vendor_id = Vendor::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id')->first(); 
    return $vendor_id === $product->vendor_id;
}

public function delete(User $user, Product $product)
{
    $vendor_id = Vendor::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id')->first();
    return $vendor_id === $product->vendor_id;
}

public function restore(User $user, Product $product)
{
    //
}

public function forceDelete(User $user, Product $product)
{
    //
}
}
```

I am allowing user to edit, update, delete the product if they owns it. According to the laravel documentation we can use authorizeResource method if we have used resource controller. That is why I added this:

```
$this->authorizeResource(Product::class, 'products');
```

in the `ProductController`

But when I tried to delete, edit the products own by the specific vendor, it says, 403 authorized. More importantly I am using `view`

```
@foreach($allProducts as $productLists) 
@can('view', $productLists)
      codes....
   @endcan
@endforeach
```

But, if I do

```
public function viewAny(User $user)
{
    return false;
}
```

instead of

```
public function viewAny(User $user)
{
    return true;
}
```

Even the admin and editor cannot add, edit, update and view the products. What is wrong going here?

**Edit**
In my `web.php` I have used resource route like below:

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

Comment: In your controller, you have `update` method in the controller, you also needs to have `update` in your policy.  Same goes for store and delete. You have the table correspondence at the end of the chapter https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier There is `update` method in `ProductPolicy` itself. Or you are trying to draw my attention some other part in the code?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't saw there was a scroll in your code

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier no problem but do you know what has gone wring here?

Comment: Perharps `$this->authorizeResource(Product::class, 'products');` the `products` should be singular ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I don't think that is the problem. According to the documentation we have to pass the route name in the second parameter of `authorizeResource`

Comment: Not the route name.  Should be route param that corresponds to model id.

Comment: @Avi Thanks. So what should be there?

Comment: Can you share your route ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Do you mean my code in `web.php`

Comment: yes (bablabal I need extra chars to post the message)

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I have added the code for the `Product` resource controller.

Comment: I see; `Route::resource('products','ProductController');` will generate `Route::post('/products/{product}'....)` (and more)  we are interested by `{product}`. So in `$this->authorizeResource(Product::class, 'products');`  `products` should be singular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218868/discussion-between-gaurav-and-clement-baconnier).

Comment: The authorizeResource method accepts the model's class name as its first argument but you are using the wrong name(products) it should be "product".

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the type of the foreign field is coming like a string, not an integer and you are using === operator instead of ==.

So there are two possible solutions.

> use == instead of == operator

or convert the string into an integer before compare

> return $vendor_id === (int)$product->vendor_id;

and The authorizeResource method accepts the model's class name as its first argument but you are using the wrong name(products) it should be "product".
I think it should be(remove s from products)

> $this->authorizeResource(Product::class, 'product');

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Vendor;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ProductPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function before($user, $ability){
        if($user->roles == 'admin' || $user->roles == 'editor'){
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function view(User $user, Product $product)
    {
        $vendor_id = Vendor::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id')->first();
        return $vendor_id == $product->vendor_id; // issue here
    }

    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function update(User $user, Product $product)
    {
        $vendor_id = Vendor::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id')->first(); 
        return $vendor_id === (int)$product->vendor_id; // issue here
    }

    public function delete(User $user, Product $product)
    {
        $vendor_id = Vendor::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id')->first();
        return $vendor_id === (int)$product->vendor_id; // issue here
    }

    public function restore(User $user, Product $product)
    {
        //
    }

    public function forceDelete(User $user, Product $product)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You can run the following statement in any policy function(where you compare the things) then you will get the idea.

```
echo gettype($vendor_id).", ".gettype($product->vendor_id);
die;
```

Comment: The authorizeResource method accepts the model's class name as its first argument but you are using the wrong name(products) it should be "product".

Comment: then show the error. we will get the idea after seeing the error

Comment: and also show the output of the $user->roles statement the run in before function.

Comment: Can you please join the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218868/